# Iterating list problems

Tags: python-3.x

I've been having alot of trouble with this problem but have mostly solved everything except the last part. I need to iterate some loops for the list so that it fills out the whole table. What I am doing is trying to combine to text files

```
for example pulsars1=
1
2
3
4
5

and signals1=
M
I
N
N
A
```

so i want the list to look like

```
1M, 2I, 3N etc..
```

I have almost gotten it except that it's only doing the first two entries of this list..
it looks like this:

```
This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory
============================================================
It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, 
then combines them and displays the results.

Pulsar name file: pulsars1.txt
Signal strength: signals1.txt

Analyzing data from pulsars1.txt and signals1.txt files...
      Reading from pulsars1.txt ...
      Reading from signals1.txt ...
      Combining values...

The combined BOOYA data includes 3 values.
1M
```

so as you can see it is combing the first line but then not doing so for the rest.
this is the code I have now.

```
# defining the read function
def read(pulsar_name,signal_strength):
    #opening and reading data from first line
    pulsars = open(pulsar_name,"r").readlines()
    #opening and reading data from second line
    signals = open(signal_strength,"r").readlines()
    #creating a new empty list
    astro_list = []
    #appending pulsar values to list
    for all_pulse in range(0,len(signals)):
        astro_list.append(pulsars)
    #appending signal data to list
        for all_signal in range(0,len(signals)):
            astro_list.append(signals)
            for i in range(0,len(astro_list)):
                return(pulsars[i].rstrip()+signals[i])

#defining the main function
def main():

    #displaying a description of what the program does
    purpose = "This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory"
    underheading = "=" * len(purpose)
    print(purpose)
    print(underheading)
    print("It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, \nthen combines them and displays the results.")
    #accepting inputs from the user about file names
    pulsar_name = input("\nPulsar name file: ")
    signal_strength = input("Signal strength: ")
    #calling
    astro_list = read(pulsar_name,signal_strength)
    read(pulsar_name,signal_strength)
    #reading values
    print("\nAnalyzing data from" , pulsar_name, "and", signal_strength, "files...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,pulsar_name,"...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,signal_strength,"...")
    print("     ","Combining values...")
    #displaying the top part of the table/ counting the number of elements that are in the list
    print("\nThe combined BOOYA data includes" ,len(astro_list), "values.")
    print(read(pulsar_name,signal_strength))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

any suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: You are returning a value in your read method.  This automatically kills the `for` loop.  That is why you are only getting one result.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a good idea, to use `zip` here. If you are sure, that your two text files always contain the same number of entries, `zip` will do, but to make it more flexible, you could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def main():
    #input of pulsar_name and signal_strength as described by you, e.g. you end up with
    #pulsar_name = "test1.txt"
    #signal_strength = "test2.txt"
    #read file and remove whitespaces and newline escape code
    pulsar_list = [line.strip(" \n") for line in open(pulsar_name, "r")]
    signal_list = [line.strip(" \n") for line in open(signal_strength, "r")]
    #combine the two list and mark those entries without a counterpart
    astro_list = list(zip_longest(pulsar_list, signal_list, fillvalue = "-missing-"))
    #print out the list
    for i, item in enumerate(astro_list):
        print("Entry #", i, "for astrolist is ", item, "and consists of pulsar data", 
              pulsar_list[i], "and signal strength", signal_list[i])


main()
```

The output loop is just an example to show you, how to access data in all three lists. The output won't work properly, if `pulsar` and `signal` don't have the same length. I could have written it differently to take into account lists of unequal length, but since this is just an example, I didn't want to make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: This is a better answer to learn from.  I just debugged until her code was stable.  This actually has extra knowledge.  +1 @MrT